# Javascript element visibility not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that I need help with. This will be a google style search function and I will have a separate page for screen reader users. My form looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <input type="text" name="search" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>" onfocus="display_results_table()"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">
  <input type="reset" name="reset" tabindex="<?php echo $tab++; ?>">
</div>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

The reason I am using PHP to do my tab indexes is so I don't have to put them in manually and I have an element called results beneath that. I have styled each element like so:

```
#main {
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 25%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: #000000 medium solid;
}       


#results     {
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: #000000 thin solid;
    display: none;
}
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_results_table()
{
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.width = "30%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.borderRadius = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.borderRight = "0";
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

The element mail performs as expected however I cannot get the results element to display. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are defining styles for `#results ` with your javascript, but you don't create it anywhere...

Comment: I don't see any element with id="results" in your code.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed it off. Edited it now

Comment: There are some details missing that matter because I took your code and made a fiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/6shq9r8n/

Comment: Is it possible the element is displaying, it just doesn't appear to be because the background color is the same as the page and it has no content? Have you inspected the page?

Comment: Also, I recommend using a variable to hold the `main` element instead of accessing the DOM for each manipulation: `var main = document.getElementById("main");` `main.style.marginLeft = 0%`

Comment: Okay... I think I've got it now